# How do I dynamically retrieve values from related objects using getSObject?

Tags: apex, soql

I have an object called `Schedule__c`, related to this there are 12 lookups for each month. i.e. `Month_1__c` which links to a `Invoice__c` object.

I have a dynamic query that looks at each month and retrieves value from that object called `Cost__c`.

My query looks like this (shortened it to understand it quicker)

```
SELECT Invoice_Month_1__r.Cost__c, Invoice_Month_2__r.Cost__c, Invoice_Month_3__r.Cost__c  
FROM Schedule__c
```

In the following code, I try to extract the values from my Cost__c column but get a failure saying `invalid relationship` in execution.

```
for(Payment_Schedule__c record_i : (query)) {
     Invoice__c inv = (Invoice__c)record_i.getSObject('Invoice__c');
     System.debug(inv);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Invoice__c` just use `Invoice_Month_1__r` (or correspondant lookup name):

```
Invoice__c inv = (Invoice__c)record_i.getSObject('Invoice_Month_1__r ');
 System.debug(inv);
```